# Leaving 6 months after an internal promotion. How to show on CV?

Tags: resume, job-change, promotion

I worked at a company for 2 years and I then became ACCA qualified. I was promoted to a role within the same team, but with different and greater level of responsibilities. At the time, I wanted to leave the company, but, due to the convenience and package offered, I accepted. I believe this to be a mistake in hindsight.

6 months later, I’m still really not enjoying life there and need to move on. But I’m unsure how to present this short 6 month period on my CV, which was different from the job I was doing up until my promotion.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I would show this?

Comment: hi and welcome to Workplace. What type of position are you applying for? Maybe specifying your roles (the ones that lasted 2 years and 6 months) would be helpful for answering

Comment: So you have been at your company for 2.5 years, just on different teams?

Comment: Don't feel like you owe your employers anything.  It's ultimately a business contract.  If you want to move on to other jobs, your employers also won't have to pay your boosted salary anymore.  If that company feels that it's losing more than it's gaining by your leaving, they can make a counteroffer.  If not, you wanted to leave anyway.  Ultimately it is a gain on your part.

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand the premise of this question, can you make it a bit more clear about what you want? You certainly know (or, don't you?) how to put multiple experiences in a CV..what is special about this case?

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your responses. To give you a bit more back ground, I already have a full CV up until my promotion, I’m an accountant & the promotion was within the same team but different role with more responsibilities. I guess it’s more how to show it as it has been so short & for a role like this, 6mnths is not enough time to fully get your feet under the table with it.

Comment: Currently for every role on my CV I have responsibilities/day-to-day of what my position involves & then key achievements. I didn’t want to merge the 2 roles as that could be confusing to potential employers, but then should I be using less space for this role as it’s been so short (& possibly 6mnths is not enough time to really achieve anything CV worthy?), even though it’s the highest position I’ve had in my career?

Answer (score 5):

I would just list the promoted title under the same company as the previous title e.g.

```
Bob's Burgers | New York, New York

   HR Manager | Oct 2018 - current

   Talent Coordinator | Oct 2016 - Oct 2018
```

The shorter duration in the new role is not enough to leave it off your resume in my opinion. I generally wouldn't leave a promotion off your resume in general.